# How do I access the data from the public ClassName in another part of the code?

Tags: java

I am trying to access the `String` called `curLocation` that is in the bracket next to `public LineChart_AWT` in the `DefaultCategoryDataset createDataset()` how can I do that?
I tried to set it to another value or call it in the bracket in `DefaultCategoryDataset createDataset()`. However, neither of them worked, what do I do?

```
public class LineChart_AWT extends ApplicationFrame
{
    ArrayList<Integer> levels;
    ArrayList<Date> dates;
    public LineChart_AWT(String applicationTitle, String chartTitle, String curLocation) {
        super(applicationTitle);
        String location = curLocation;
        JFreeChart lineChart = ChartFactory.createLineChart(
                chartTitle,
                "Time", "Tank Level",
                createDataset(),
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
                true, true, false);

        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(lineChart);
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(560, 367));
        setContentPane(chartPanel);
    }
    DefaultCategoryDataset createDataset() {

        DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
        dataset.addValue(15, "Houston", "1970");
        dataset.addValue(200, "Houston", "1980");
        dataset.addValue(60, "Houston", "1990");
        dataset.addValue(120, "Houston", "2000");
        dataset.addValue(240, "Houston", "2010");
        dataset.addValue(300, "Houston", "2014");
        return dataset;
    }

}
```

Comment: By creating an instance property like you've done for `levels` and `dates`? By changing the method signature to `createDataset` and passing it in as a parameter? It's not entirely clear what is meant by "call it in the bracket": methods take parameters, and are called with parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create getters and setters to access you private fields. Here's an example

```
public class LineChart_AWT extends ApplicationFrame
{
    ArrayList<Integer> levels;
    ArrayList<Date> dates;
    private String curLocation;
    public LineChart_AWT(String applicationTitle, String chartTitle, String curLocation) {
        super(applicationTitle);
        this.curLocation = curLocation; //Setting the value here.
        JFreeChart lineChart = ChartFactory.createLineChart(
                chartTitle,
                "Time", "Tank Level",
                createDataset(),
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
                true, true, false);

        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(lineChart);
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(560, 367));
        setContentPane(chartPanel);
    }
    DefaultCategoryDataset createDataset() {

        DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
        dataset.addValue(15, "Houston", "1970");
        dataset.addValue(200, "Houston", "1980");
        dataset.addValue(60, "Houston", "1990");
        dataset.addValue(120, "Houston", "2000");
        dataset.addValue(240, "Houston", "2010");
        dataset.addValue(300, "Houston", "2014");
        return dataset;
    }
   
   //Update or set the value
   public void setCurLocation(String curLocation){
       this.curLocation = curLocation;
   }

   //Fetch data from this class.
   public String getCurLocation(){
       return curLocation;
   }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LineChart_AWT lc = new LineChart_AWT("APP_TITLE", "APP_CHART_TITLE", "CURLOCATION: KARACHI");
    String location = lc.getCurLocation(); //Getting data from LineChart_AWT class

}
```